# Firefox overflow:scroll resize issue

Tags: css, firefox, resize, scroll, overflow

In Firefox......

```
<div id="container" style="overflow:scroll; width:400px; height:500px">
      <div id="content" style="height:500px; width:800px"/>
</div>
```

The "container" DIV should have scroll bars since the div with id "content" is wider than it.

If, using JavaScript (see below), I reset the size of the "content" div to "200px", I would expect the scroll bars on the div "container" to disappear. They dont, unless I manually resize the the browser window.

```
function Resize() {
   document.getElement("content").style.width="200px";
}
```

I tried forcing a reflow on container by applying a css class. This didnt work...

```
function Resize() {
   document.getElement("content").style.width="200px";
   document.getElement("container").className="test";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `overflow: scroll;` should force scrollbars to be on.
If you want them to appear and disappear with the content size, try `overflow: auto;`